# undefined when contract code is copied in Geth

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, geth

I'm trying to create a contract in Ethereum private network.

What I tried was:

Created the following contract in browser-solidity.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract SingleNumRegister {
    uint storedData;
    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() public constant returns (uint retVal)  {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

And copied web3 deploy code as below.

```
var singlenumregisterContract = 
web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"retVal","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);
var singlenumregister = singlenumregisterContract.new(
{
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '0x6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b60d38061001d6000396000f3006060604052600436106049576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff16806360fe47b114604e5780636d4ce63c14606e575b600080fd5b3415605857600080fd5b606c60048080359060200190919050506094565b005b3415607857600080fd5b607e609e565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b8060008190555050565b600080549050905600a165627a7a72305820cc0de7aa0d676f08b124d9f878aeecd0c305703a9d59ccde63b557dd8585dfcb0029', 
     gas: '4700000'
}, function (e, contract){
console.log(e, contract);
if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
     console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
}
})
```

Then, copied in the console.

```
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
Unlock account 0x24636f1423f131f5441fbee83323c53c59af247d
Passphrase: 
true
> var singlenumregisterContract = 
web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":
[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":
[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},
{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"retVal","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);
undefined
>
> var singlenumregister = singlenumregisterContract.new(
...    {
......      from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
......      data: '0x6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b60d38061001d6000396000f3006060604052600436106049576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff16806360fe47b114604e5780636d4ce63c14606e575b600080fd5b3415605857600080fd5b606c60048080359060200190919050506094565b005b3415607857600080fd5b607e609e565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b8060008190555050565b600080549050905600a165627a7a72305820cc0de7aa0d676f08b124d9f878aeecd0c305703a9d59ccde63b557dd8585dfcb0029', 
......      gas: '4700000'
......    }, function (e, contract){
......     console.log(e, contract);
......     if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
.........          console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
.........     }
......  })
null [object Object]
undefined
>
```

As above, I got undefined both scripts.

How can I solve this?

I use the environment below:

- MacOSX 10.12.6
- Geth: 1.7.3-stable
- Solc: 0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.Darwin.appleclang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `JSON.parse()` your ABI.

```
var jsonAbi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"retVal","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]');

var singlenumregisterContract = web3.eth.contract(jsonAbi);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and realized that I could not even define `var = "test"`. I searched on the internet but could not find any answer for it.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What is var = "test"? I ran your code in my console after adding the JSON parsing and it worked just fine. Contract mined! address: 0xc39b2048db8c32677f8a7739dbd591363651552b transactionHash: 0xbd14e36069196d4d004c03b577c99735159fe293f363092f4b82ab87a9a065ae

Comment: I mean `> var jsonAbi = JSON.parse...` in Geth console returns undefined, too. So I tried `> var x = "test"` and it returns undefined as well. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Kind of. "undefined" is the result of your variable declaration, not the value of the variable itself. Type `x` <enter>. You should see "test" returned.

Comment: Thanks again. I could get the contract address successfully! But what `var ....` returns "undefined" is normal behavior?